# When is the convolution of symmetric bimodal densities unimodal?

Tags: references, density-function, convolution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be real valued random variables with densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$. It is well known that if $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are symmetric about zero and unimodal then their convolution $f_X \ast f_Y$ is unimodal about 0.

There are examples of bimodal distributions, symmetric about 0, whose convolutions are also unimodal, provided their densities are not 'too bimodal'. One such example of a unimodal convolution is given here:

https://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/uncorrelated-sum-pdensity.pdf

My question: If $f$ is symmetric about 0 and bimodal, are there any general conditions under which it is 'not too bimodal' for $f \ast f$ to have a unimodal density?

Given such an $f$, the direct approach would be to check the monotonicity of the convolution integral

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\cdot f(z-x) dx$ for $z \in (- \infty,0]$

Except in special cases, it is not easy to verify that the derivative w.r.t $z$ is positive everywhere. Are there any families of distributions for which this has been done, or any general methods to verify this property for convolution integrals?

One reason this might be hard is if $f$ has compact support. For example, let 
$f_X(x)=\frac{4}{3\pi}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\left(1+2x^{2}\right)$ for $x \in [-1,1]$

This is a bimodal density whose convolution (ignoring constants) for $z \in [-2,0]$ is given by

$\int_{x=-1}^{z+1} \sqrt{1-x^{2}}\left(1+2x^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-(z-x)^{2}}\left(1+2(z-x)^{2}\right)dx$

As far as I can tell this doesn't have a closed form, but when computed numerically has positive derivative on $(-2,0)$.

Comment: 1. Are you sure z should be the upper limit of that integral?   2. It looks to me like there's a simple form for the derivative of a convolution integral. $\frac{d}{dx} f*g = f'*g = f*g'$. I don't know whether this helps you much though.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.